# VueJS - Swap component on click

Tags: vue.js

In my application I have many buttons. When I press it the button I would like to load a template (that replaces the selected button):

Templates:

```
Vue.component('component-1', {...});
Vue.component('component-2', {...});
```

Buttons:

```
<div id="toReplace">
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

In this case, when I press `Button1` the content of the div `toReplace` should be `component-1`. 
Sure, each component should have a "close" button that will show the buttons again (in short, the div `toReplace`) on press.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to bind a variable to `:is` property. And change this variable on button click. Also you will need to combine it with some `v-show` condition. Like so:

```html
<div id="toReplace">
    <div :is="currentComponent"></div>
    <div v-show="!currentComponent" v-for="component in componentsArray">
      <button @click="swapComponent(component)">{{component}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button @click="swapComponent(null)">Close</button>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    currentComponent: null,
    componentsArray: ['foo', 'bar']
  },
  components: {
    'foo': {
      template: '<h1>Foo component</h1>'
    },
    'bar': {
      template: '<h1>Bar component</h1>'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponent: function(component)
    {
      this.currentComponent = component;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is quick example:

http://jsbin.com/miwuduliyu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: How would you pass props to the component in this method?

Comment: @srik To also pass dynamic props, you gotta use `v-bind` without argument, proving it with an object of prop names and values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-bind:is="CurrentComponent"` and `@click=ChangeComponent('SecondComponent')`. **The argument has to be a string**. To use the `<component/>` make sure your **ExampleComponent has a slot**

```
<Template>
  <div>
    <ExampleComponent>
      <component v-bind:is = "CurrentComponent"/>
    </ExampleCompoent>
    <button @click="ChangeComponent('SecondComponent')">
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ExampleComponent from '@/components/ExampleComponent.vue'
  import SecondComponent from '@/components/SecontComponent.vue'
  export default{
    ...
    data(){
      return{
        CurrentComponet:null
      }
    }
    methods:{
      ChangeComponent(NewComponent){
        this.CurrentComponent = NewComponent
    }
```