# VueJS template - Flip between Login Form & Register Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to Flip between 'Login Form' & 'Register Form'. I tried to use code which I came across on codepen [Flat HTML5/CSS3 Login Form](https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/rxddKy). The code works just fine, but when I integrate the HTML code within a Vue Template the Form does not flip to the 'Create an account' form. I have observed that there is something to correct in the JavaScript but I am not able to understand exactly what.

My code is as below:

HTML

```
<template id="login-page"> // PROBLEM When this Tag is added and called using VueJS component
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</template>  // PROBLEM When this Tag is added and called using VueJS component
```

VueJS

```
// Vue component: login-page
const LoginPage = {
    template: '#login-page',
    data() {
        return {
            login_message: 'Please enter your credentials to login.',
            loginStage: 'login-form',
            }
        },
    }
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery within Vue, are you sure you have imported the jQuery library and that the $ reference has been set? 

Ultimately, it is just toggling css properties with the addition of animation, this can be done easily without jQuery if needed.

Comment: Yes, I have set the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Fred has accepted @chr's answer, this is (still) a mis-use of Vue.
(Note this not an attempt to reproduce the working fiddle, but to answer the general question of how to *Flip between 'Login Form' & 'Register Form'* using a more Vue-oriented approach)

In the Vue way of doing things the switch between the login form and the register form should be done with markup, using [Vue conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) rather than calling functions `showRegisterForm()` and `showLoginForm()`.
`toggleForm` doesn't require a parameter because the model knows what the value of `currentForm` is already.

An `if` and `else` is the simplest approach, making use of a property in your Vue model, such as `currentForm: 'login'` that *chr* introduced in their answer.
The HTML needs only slight changes

```
<div id="login-page" class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form v-if="currentForm.toLowerCase() === 'register'" class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered?
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm()">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form v-else class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered?
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm()">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

A partial look at the model needed for this could be

```
const model = new Vue({
    data : {
        'currentForm' : 'login',
        ...
    },
    ...
    methods : {
        toggleForm() {
            this.currentForm = this.currentForm === 'login' ? 'register' : 'login';
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

When the value of `currentForm` changes Vue will take care of changing which of the forms will display.

Also see the answer to the question *[VueJS - Swap component on click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39391218/17300)* for a more generalized approach.

Comment: That works as well and is a much neater code, except that the first form should have the register in single quotes i.e. 'register'

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the use of Vue as library and Vue as framework. It looks like, you are actually trying to use Vue as library, so I changed the code accordingly, [here is myfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s63oz4L2/34/). You can just need to add a transition, for more information look into the documentation [Enter/Leave & List Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html).

HTML:

```
<div id="login-page" class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" v-show="showRegisterForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm('login')">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" v-show="showLoginForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm('register')">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#login-page',
  data() {
      return {
        login_message: 'Please enter your credentials to login.',
        loginStage: 'login-form',
        currentForm: 'login',
      }
    },
  computed: {
        showRegisterForm() {
        return this.currentForm === 'register';
    },
    showLoginForm() {
        return this.currentForm === 'login';
    },
  },
    methods: {
        toggleForm(formName) {
        this.currentForm = formName;
    },
  },
});
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
```

Comment: That works as desired for me. Only the first two lines of the JavaScript code had to be changed in since in my case I have an existing Vue which calls the Login Component which then activates the Login Template.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you wanted to use Vue without jQuery. My bad :), at least we solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[@chr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5534460/chr) solutions works for me except the the first two lines of the JavaScript code that had to be changed since in my case I have an existing Vue which calls the Login Component which then activates the Login Template.

JavaScript

```
// Vue component: login-page
const LoginPage = {
    template: '#login-page',
    data() {
        return {
            login_message: 'Please enter your credentials to login.',
            currentForm: 'login',
            }
        },
    computed: {
        showRegisterForm() {
            return this.currentForm === 'register';
        },
        showLoginForm() {
            return this.currentForm === 'login';
            },
        },
    methods: {
        toggleForm(formName) {
        this.currentForm = formName;
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stephen P's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) code works as well and is much neater, except that the first form should have the register in single quotes i.e. 'register', which is corrected below.

HTML

```
<div id="login-page" class="login-page">
    <span><h1>{{currentForm.toUpperCase()}} FORM</h1></span>
    <span><h5>Please enter your credentials to {{currentForm.toLowerCase()}}.</h5></span>
    <div class="form">
        <form v-if="currentForm.toLowerCase() === 'register'" class="register-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
        <button>create</button>
        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm()">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form v-else class="login-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button>login</button>
        <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleForm()">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
// Vue component: login-page
const LoginPage = {
    template: '#login-page',
    data() {
        return {
            currentForm: 'login',
            }
        },
    methods: {
        toggleForm()
        {
            this.currentForm = this.currentForm === 'login' ? 'register' : 'login';
        }
    },
}
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
```